# How to dynamically adding new roles with permissions in .net and angular?

Tags: .net, angular, permissions, authorization, roles

Im new with .net and angular , but i found an exemple of what i want (dynamic roles and permissions management and authorization) the problem it's an MVC web application using views , and i want to applicate the same logic to a web api so i can work the frontend with angular .
this is the article of the example  "[permission-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core/)
I started to try working it but didnt work.
can u give me any insight on the matter please?

this is an exemple of what i tried

```
namespace roles_permissions_mangement.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public class RolesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        public RolesController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<IdentityRole>>> GetRoles()
        {
            var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(roles);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddRole([FromBody] string roleName)
        {
            if (roleName != null)
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                return Ok(new { Message = "Role added successfully." });
            }

            return BadRequest(new { Message = "somthing went wrong" });
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace roles_permissions_mangement.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public class PermissionController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public PermissionController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [HttpGet("{roleId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PermissionViewModel>> GetRolePermissions(string roleId)
        {
            var model = new PermissionViewModel();
            var allPermissions = new List<RoleClaimsViewModel>();
            allPermissions.GetPermissions(typeof(Permissions.Products), roleId);

            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
            model.RoleId = roleId;

            var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            var allClaimValues = allPermissions.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var roleClaimValues = claims.Select(a => a.Value).ToList();
            var authorizedClaims = allClaimValues.Intersect(roleClaimValues).ToList();

            foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
            {
                permission.Selected = authorizedClaims.Any(a => a == permission.Value);
            }

            model.RoleClaims = allPermissions;
            return Ok(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRolePermissions([FromBody] PermissionViewModel model)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.RoleId);
            var claims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                await _roleManager.RemoveClaimAsync(role, claim);
            }

            var selectedClaims = model.RoleClaims.Where(a => a.Selected).ToList();

            foreach (var claim in selectedClaims)
            {
                await _roleManager.AddPermissionClaim(role, claim.Value);
            }

            return Ok(new { Message = "Role permissions updated successfully." });
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace roles_permissions_mangement
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("app");
                try
                {
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                    await Seeds.DefaultRoles.SeedAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                    await Seeds.DefaultUsers.SeedBasicUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                    await Seeds.DefaultUsers.SeedSuperAdminAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                    logger.LogInformation("Finished Seeding Default Data");
                    logger.LogInformation("Application Starting");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogWarning(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

```
namespace roles_permissions_mangement
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "roles_permissions_mangement", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "roles_permissions_mangement v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I know its wrong so i will be greatfull for any help, or if u have any other methode to do the same with angular and .net tell me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could add more details about what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Then the answer could be a bit more targeted with less assumptions.

I only overflew the tutorial, but the permissions are not handled on the server-side in the controllers but in the views instead. So it basically relies on the server-rendered razor pages to work and you won't be able to achieve the same result with an Angular app. Even though you could request the user's permissions from the server and render your menu accordingly, it has no security benefit at all since the user can still manipulate the site as much as they want. After all it is just Javascript.

That being said you still would need to secure your controller actions accordingly with the permission policies. Even in razor pages, the conditional rendering of components, server-side or client-side doesn't prevent anyone from just calling the controller actions directly. So you definitely end up having to hardcode something into your server. In this case the permissions instead of the roles. While the permission approach is much more flexible it adds also a lot more complexity to the whole authorization process. And from experience, I can tell you that it can be quite the pain in the A to maintain a permission-based authorization.

First of all, you should ask yourself if you really need such a flexible approach. Will you have many different user types with a lot of different permissions or do you have e.g. admins that can that should be able to handle each of their users permissions in a granular way? In our case we had basic users that could add sub-users for their company with a lot of different permissions. So we only had a few roles and the permissions were related directly to a user.

So if you don't have similar requirements, in 9 out of 10 cases the role-based approach is more than sufficient and saves you a lot of hassle.

That being said, the code should actually mostly work. You just need to use a different kind of login for your Angular app. Myself, I never used Identity for .Net Core. We usually implement a simple custom JWT Token provider in simple cases, a fully featured Identity Server or a third party solution like authO. So I cannot really help you there, but that would be the direction to go. How to make Asp.Net Identity Sign In work with Angular. Aside from that the controller just return data for authorized super admins and you can handle this data the same in Angular.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).